# Datomic not a valid :uri for attribute

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying to insert a value on an attribute defined as

```
{:db/ident       :foo/uri
 :db/valueType   :db.type/uri
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
 :db/doc         "Test attribute of value type uri."}
```

I'm inserting

```
{:foo/uri "scheme://host/path"}
```

and get

```
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at datomic.client.api.async/ares (async.clj:58).
Value scheme://host/path is not a valid :uri for attribute :foo/uri
```

I'm lost as to what to insert here. It should be a string, right?  No reader literal?

I found zero examples of this online. Also took a look at the [java class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-net-uri-class-java/) corresponding to this but no illumination.  Or maybe it needs an instance of `java.net.URI`, so to put it in `edn` we'd need to install our own reader literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does need to be an instance of `java.net.URI`.

If it's part of your code, you could wrap it up when creating it:

```
{:foo/uri (new java.net.URI "scheme://host/path")}
```

If you want to read it in from an edn file, then you could use a custom tag, say `#URI`, in the file and pass a custom reader function as an option to `edn/read-string`:

```
;;; in some file located at `path`
{:foo/uri #URI"scheme://host/path"}

;;; code to read the file at `path`
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
(-> path
    slurp
    (edn/read-string {:readers {'URI #(new java.net.URI %)}})
```

You could also do this with `clojure.tools.reader`, which allows for unsafe code execution (so probably not recommended):

```
;;; use reader tools
(require '[clojure.tools.reader :as r])
(r/read-string "{:foo/uri #=(new java.net.URI \"scheme://host/path\")}")
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick - I was already using a function (per 'entity') that pipelines the attribute map prior to sending it off to a transaction, doing a few handy transforms. So, that now checks for the attributes that are uri's, and swaps in the needed java object for the string. This way, all client code can just pass a plain string for the uri attribute; the transformation is done in one place.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use dt.type/uri attribute? Why not just store it in the database as db.type/string (strings all the way down!) and only convert to URI if needed, outside the database. I ask because I am currently debating whether to use db.type/uri or db.type/string and not sure if the transformation is worth it.

Comment: There isn't a reason I have to use it that I know of - I asked myself the same question - explanation: i'm just taking it on trust at the moment that because the uri type exists, that it adds some value; not clear what that is yet. haven't deployed anything live yet, so would review the decision before any deploy. yes, may well switch back to string.